# Convert data to date, month, year in lubridate in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a `dataframe` with a column with dates, the column is named `dateDecision`. They are in the format `1970/01/01`. I am trying to split the date into `year`, `month` and `date` columns. I used the following code

```
df %>% mutate(year = lubridate::year(dateDecision), 
                month = lubridate::month(dateDecision), 
                day = lubridate::day(dateDecision))
```

I get an error saying Error in `as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

When I use dput(head(df,10)), this is the output

```
structure(list(term = c("1791", "1791", "1791", "1791", "1791", 
"1792", "1792", "1792", "1792", "1792"), dateDecision = c("8/3/1791", 
"8/3/1791", "8/3/1791", "8/3/1791", "8/3/1791", "8/11/1792", 
"8/11/1792", "8/11/1792", "8/11/1792", "8/11/1792"), decisionType = c("6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8"), dateArgument = c("8/2/1791", 
"8/2/1791", "8/2/1791", "8/2/1791", "8/2/1791", "8/9/1792", "8/9/1792", 
"8/9/1792", "8/9/1792", "8/9/1792")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert you `dateDecision`column to a date first using lubridate

```
df %>% mutate(dateDecision=lubridate::mdy(dateDecision),
              year = lubridate::year(dateDecision), 
              month = lubridate::month(dateDecision), 
              day = lubridate::day(dateDecision))
```

Comment: That just gives me NA values for all four columns @fmarm

Comment: Could you please add the result of `dput(head(df,10))` to your post so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you for being so prompt!

Comment: Ok, got the error your format is not  'YYYY/MM/DD' but seems to be MM/DD/YYYY, I changed the function from `ymd` to `mdy`. From your data it seems possible that it could be DD/MM/YYYY (no values greater than 12 in the first ten lines), in this case you need to use `dmy`function

Comment: I get this error Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: Are you sure you have `df %>%` before the mutate call?

Comment: Yes I do. That's why I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

First use `anytime::anydate()`library to convert you `dateDecision`column to a date:

```
library(anytime)
    date <- "1970/01/01"
    anytime::anydate(date)
    [1] "1970-01-01"
```

Then run your mutate. You can use `tk_augment_timeseries_signature()` from `timetk` as well and only select only `year`, `month` and `date` columns.

```
library(timetk)
library(tidyverse)

# make some reproducible data
dates <-
    seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), by = 'days') 

dates <- as_tibble(dates)

#add the time signature features including year, month, day, day of week, day of month, #day of year, hour, minute, second to the input data

dates %>% 
tk_augment_timeseries_signature()
```